# Does Windows phone 8 panorama control not swipe with only one panorama item?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I was porting my Windows Phone 7.5 app to Windows Phone 8 and I came to know that in WP8 Panorama control doesn't swipe or flick with only one Panorama item.

But in my WP 7.5 app I was using only one Panorama item to show content from server. And I have also checked my WP 7.5 app on WP 8's Emulator and it worked fine for me.
I don't have a Windows Phone 8 device so I just want a confirmation whether my WP 7.5 app would work fine with a single Panorama item in Windows Phone 8 too, or do I need to make at least 2 items in Panorama control?

Answer (score 0):

A WP7 app run on a WP8 device or emulator should behave the same as it did on WP7. That said you can check by running the WP7 app on the WP8 emulator (assuming you have the WP8 SDK if you're doing a port). You can use the application deployment tools to load your WP7 XAP onto the WP8 emulator of your choice, or from VS2012 also if your project still targets WP7.5 and hasn't been upgraded to WP8.